# phpMyAdmin: theme per database - doesn't work without page refresh

Tags: phpmyadmin, themes

Because we have a mysql server with two similar databases plus a backup database. We work with phpMyAdmin 4,9,5 for development and maintenance.

The DBs being so similar and sometimes copies of one another, is important for us developers that it's immediately clear in which DB we are.

For this, I modified the metro theme to look at the DB currently loaded and pick an according color scheme.

This works, but only after you manually refresh the page in your browser. (Also when you open links in new tabs instead of the same tab.)

The point is that phpMyAdmin uses AJAX to reload parts of the page whenever you click any link within phpmyadmin. It does not reload the basic page and so it also does not reload the css.

In php I can easily detect a database change, and if detected, I want the whole new (phpmyadmin) page to load, including css. However, it will always just load the new content via ajax and I don't know how to make it (re)load the whole page instead, other than manually hitting the browser's refresh button.

I made an include file switchTheme.php to include somewhere in a source file. I was first thinking of header("Refresh:1") after a database change to simulate the manual refresh, but since everything is loaded via AJAX, of course that won't work. i need to refresh the old page, not the new content.

Can anyone knowledgeable of phpMyAdmin think of a simple solution for this simple problem? I am thinking in the following directions:

- Disable AJAX loading altogether (seems rather radical and not very
  efficient plus I don't know how and if it's possible)
- There is a
  ThemePerServer configuration in phpMyAdmin, this is so close to
  a fictional "ThemePerDatabase" - could something be done with that? Probably not.
- Detecting a database change in php and simulating a browser page
  refresh via javascript, I can make an include php file for that, but
  where do I include it?! Adding a config.footer.inc.php or
  config.header.inc.php doesn't help; those files are not loaded after clicking a link in phpmyadmin.

NB The database structure is a given, I just want a simple solution for this, no lectures on database organisation or the dangers of changing source code, thanks! I know all that. We're aiming for short term practicality here. Small company, little time.

CentOs 7, php 5.6, myphpadmin 4.9.5.

To get a picture: this is what I added to `themes/metro/layout.inc.php` which only works when refreshing the whole page (database names obviously changed):

```
if ( session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ) @session_start() ;
/* Theme color scheme
 * Values: "teal", "redmond", "blueeyes", "mono", "win"
 * Set this value for the desired color scheme
 */

if ( isset($_GET['db']) || ! isset($_SESSION['phpmyadminscheme']) ) {
    switch(isset($_GET['db'])?$_GET['db']:null) {
        case 'db1': $scheme ="redmond" ; break ;
        case 'db2': $scheme ="blueeyes" ; break ;
        case 'db3': $scheme ="teal" ; break ;
        case 'backup': $scheme ="mono" ; break ;
        default: $scheme ="win";
    }
   
    $_SESSION['phpmyadminscheme'] = $scheme ;
    
}
else $scheme = $_SESSION['phpmyadminscheme']?:'win' ;


$GLOBALS['cfg']['Scheme']                   = $scheme;
...
```